# CheckBox gets checked in the second click in c# GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

**Background**: The problem I have with my code is the following.  Upon the first click of a button the checkbox doesn't get the checked checkboxes, but on the second click just get all the checked checkboxes.

Here is the code:

**ASPX**

**This button execute the process..**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeletePerman" runat="server" OnClick="lbDeletePerman_Click">Yes</asp:LinkButton>
<code><asp:UpdatePanel ID="GVUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:GridView CssClass="da-table" ID="Gv_A" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID,PatientName" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="Gv_Appoint_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CbE" runat="server" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hID" Value='<%# Eval("IDENTIFICATION") %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField=""Date" HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat" HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Deleted" HeaderText="Deleted" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#:

```
protected void lbDeletePerman_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in Gv_Appoint.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox CboxElim = (CheckBox)(rowItem.Cells[0].FindControl("CbE")); 
            if (CboxElim.Checked)
            {
                LBLT.Text = "Hello"; // NO ENTERING HERE
            }

        } 
        GVUpdatePanel.Update();
    } catch (Exception er){}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**lbDeletePerman** needs to be inside UpdatePanel together with **Gv_A**.

Or use the [AsyncPostBackTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeletePerman" runat="server" 
  OnClick="lbDeletePerman_Click">Yes</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="GVUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbDeletePerman" />
      </Triggers>
      <asp:GridView>...</asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```